# Pycharm Python Console Won't Run Anything from Script

Tags: python, pycharm

I am unable to get my pycharm console to access anything from my script. Likewise, when I tell a single line of code to execute in the console, an an error like the one shown in the image is thrown. I am sure that something is not configured correctly, and would appreciate any assistance.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you didn't import your script into the console (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a generic console open that doesn't have your script loaded into in automatically. You can tell because the name of the console is "Python Console".

Right click on the code editor window, then at the bottom, click "Run file in Python Console". That will create a new console with the script loaded.

I made that into a key combination (in the Key Bindings in settings) because it's such a common task for me.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This fixed it. I'm new to pycharm and python so I haven't yet learned these basics.

Comment: @Caleb Np. That's the thing about using a beast like Pycharm or VS. It takes a while to learn how to get up and running with it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a python console. Just right click on the script name and select run or in pycharm terminal : python script.py
It depends on your scrip